# Clean Up Old Chunk Files in Webpack 4

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, commonschunkplugin

I am using splitChunks to optimize my app, but after one chunk updates, the browser pulls down all assets because clean-webpack-plugin removes the entire dist folder, changing the requested If-Modified-Since. Is there any way to clean up just the previous version of the changed chunk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour if you do a fresh build.

AFAIK, there are **two ways to accomplish incremental updates**:

1. Use [webpack's dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)
2. Start webpack in [watch mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) --> `webpack --watch --info-verbosity verbose`

With `dev-server` youre page will [automatically refresh](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-hotonly), when changes occur.

With `watch mode` you have to refresh the page manually to see the code changes